# Reading from input files with struct data type

Tags: c++, struct

```
    struct studentInfo {
        string studentFname, studentLname;
        int testScore;
        char grade;
    }student[20];
    
    void inputs(studentInfo(&student)[20]) {
        ifstream openFile;
        openFile.open("Student.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            openFile >> student[i].studentFname;
            openFile >> student[i].studentLname;
            openFile >> student[i].testScore;
        }
        openFile.close();
    }



  Student.txt file
    Duckey Donald 85
    Goof Goofy 89
    Brave Balto 93
    Snow Smitn 93
    Alice Wonderful 89
    Samina Akthar 85
    Simba Green 95
    Donald Egger 90
    Brown Deer 86
    Johny Jackson 95
    Greg Gupta 75
    Samuel Happy 80
    Danny Arora 80
    Sleepy June 70
    Amy Cheng 83
    Shelly Malik 95
    Chelsea Tomek 95
    Angela Clodfelter 95
    Allison Nields 95
    Lance Norman 88
```

I am trying to read the txt file above into a struct array. The file will not open. I'm sure the file is in the correct folder. If you need more code let me know. Any help would be nice.

Comment: What does "nothing is found in the text file" mean?

Comment: Maybe `Student.txt` is in the wrong folder. Or if this is windows and you have hide extensions enabled in the file explorer maybe you really named the file `Student.txt.txt`. If this is Visual Studio the file needs to be in the same folder as the project file. Not the location of the executable.

Comment: Most likely explanation (see it time and time again) is that you fail to open the file. **ALWAYS** check if a file open succeeds. Something like this `openFile.open("Student.txt"); if (!openFile.is_open()) cerr << "ERROR! failed to open file\n";`. If that shows that the file open is failing then we can talk about the reasons that might be.

Comment: You are most likely going to have to use a debugger. And I mean use a debugger, step through the code 1 line at a time looking at the variables after each line executed to see what is happening. Don't press a play looking button expecting the debugger to tell you anything. There is little more we can tell you because we are not sitting at your computer.

Comment: Looks like you'll want to search the internet for "C++ read files space separated" for some examples (I've already answered a couple of these on StackOverflow).

Comment: I highly recommend opening up a temporary file, writing "Hello\n" to it and close it.  Use you OS tools to find the file.  Move your data file to the same folder as this temporary file.  Alternatively, you may want to specify the full path of the file (can't go wrong here).  This allows you to access the file regardless of where your executable resides.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a binary file instead (.bin or .dat); this type of files allow you to save entire blocks of memory such as arrays and structures into a file and not only characters like in a normal .txt file.
With that you could implement something like this to read and write a struct from a binary file, you would only need to adapt it to a struct array:
[Code Sample Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ln6Gt.png)

Comment: That is not going to work with `std::string` members in the `struct` and that is likely not the issue.

Comment: Text is a variable length record.  Variable length records are not efficient for binary I/O.  The text length must be specified (before the text) or the text is read character by character until the sentinel ('\0') is read.